# Cloth simulation is acting weird when self collision enabled

Tags: cloth-simulation, geometry

I have problem with this cloth sim when self collision enabled.
I want to get a wavey and very finely wrinkled flag, here are some of screen shots

this is when self collision disabled. as a result I get cloth going through itself,

[image]

This is when self collision enabled, the flag starts to occur like a knot towards the end of its length

[image]

this is when I increased the quality , it even happen to be worse.

[image]

I tried many different settings but for some reason it didn't help much, hope you can help me with this problem thanks

Ps. I have a wind force field, however it didn't change the result even with no wind forcefield.

Comment: Maybe you should upload your .blend file, to check what's wrong

Comment: During my re-attemps, I happened delete object and model a new one and now it works normal, I don't get the weird collision problem anymore, I don't know how and why it was causing the problem, I wish I had saved a different copy and carry on trying on it, so that the original file can be uploaded here, since I don't have the source file causing problem, what shall I do now? delete the question?

Comment: Not quite specific to your question but two things that I have often found to improve cloth simulations are to a) apply the scale of all participating meshes and b) scale everything in the scene up. Seems there's quite a few  rounding errors going on when your meshes are too small...